# I am making a background in which there is an movieclip in which the animation is really high, I would like to reduce the quality

Tags: actionscript-3

I know how to make to make whole stage quality low but can't trigger the low quality of the movieclip in the bg. I tried to change stage to movieclip name also but didn't work. Is it even possible to get it work? I just want Movieclip quality low not whole bg.

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
```

Comment: There's BitmapData.drawWithQuality() but as the class name implies you trade it off for rendering the MC as a bitmap instead of a vector.

Comment: _"Is it even possible to get it work?"_ If you [**check the manual**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) there is no such "quality" setting for MovieClip. What does "low quality bg" achieve for you? Maybe there's another way if we know your end goal...

Answer (score 1):

You should build two different background prototype MCs for high quality and low quality, then exchange them whenever you want to set you background to low/high quality. However, if your background is already too simple to not be able to reduce its contents to simulate low quality, seek elsewhere to have your performance upgraded.